# 2 funciones en un boton con addEventlistener y removeEventlistener que hagan dos funciones distintas

Tags: javascript, java, funciones, botón, function

quiero hacer dos funciones en un mismo botón, pero que cuando pulses una función elimine el eventlistener y añada el de otra funcion, por ejemplo para desplazar de izquierda a derecha una capa una capa.

function desplazar(){

```
 var header = document.getElementById("header");
 header.style.float="right"


 boton_encender.addEventListener("click", desplazar_izquierda);
 boton_encender.removeEventListener("click", desplazar_derecha);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A lo mejor esta no es la respuesta que esperas pero por favor mira la siguiente demo y dime si esto es lo que quieres conseguir

```js
elBoton.addEventListener("click", ()=>{elDiv.classList.toggle("mueve")})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  transition:all 1s;
  position:relative;
  transform:translate(0,0)
}
div.mueve{ transform:translate(100px,0)}
```

```html
<div id="elDiv"></div>
<p><button id="elBoton">boton</button></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías hacer un simple chequeo, y ejecutas y agregas lo que necesites.. Algo como ésto:

```
function desplazar(){
    var header = document.getElementById("header");

    // chequea si está a la derecha
    if(header.style.float && header.style.float == "right"){
        header.style.float="right"

        boton_encender.addEventListener("click", desplazar_izquierda);
        boton_encender.removeEventListener("click", desplazar_derecha);
    }
    else{
        header.style.float="left"

        boton_encender.addEventListener("click", desplazar_derecha);
        boton_encender.removeEventListener("click", desplazar_izquierda);
    }
}
```